# Configuring SSL for web stomp in RabbitMQ?

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

I am using the RabbitMQ and Web-stomp for messaging between the server and web pages. it is works fine over HTTP connection but failed over HTTPS connection. i searched in their document and find out that i need to setup below configuration in rabbitmq.config file

```
[
  {rabbitmq_web_stomp,
      [{ssl_config, [{port,       15671},
                     {backlog,    1024},
                     {certfile,   "path/to/certs/client/cert.pem"},
                     {keyfile,    "path/to/certs/client/key.pem"},
                     {cacertfile, "path/to/certs/testca/cacert.pem"},
                     {password,   "changeme"}]}]}
].
```

so i tried to crate the certificate using OpenSSL. i searched the in internet about create certificate file , key file in open ssl and found below command.

**To create csr and key file in pem**

```
openssl.exe req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out localhost.csr.pem -keyout localhost.key.pem -subj "/CN=localhost"
```

**To create crt file**

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in localhost.csr.pem -signkey localhost.key.pem -out localhost.crt.pem
```

i don't whether is it is correct or not and also i don't know how to create the cacert file in open SSL and how to configure the files to use with web stomp . Please help me to get out of this!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this tool for creating certificates: https://github.com/michaelklishin/tls-gen and it would be better to use Erlang 17.1 due to some SSL features implemented in later Erlang releases